# How to put bootstrap design in CheckboxSelectMultiple on django forms

Tags: python, django

I have a dynamic column requirement in database and in my forms.py i have this
RequirementForm to populate the number of requirement row in the database to html.

```
class RequirementForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ApplicantInfo

        fields = ('requirement',)
        widgets = {
            'requirement': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        }
```

Is there a way to put a bootstrap design on this one? because on my html code i only have this:

```
{% extends 'applicant/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<center>
    <!-- Default unchecked -->
    <form method = "post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
</center>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a init fun to the form:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for myField in self.fields:
            self.fields[myField].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

Also, remember to add bootstrap CSS and js to template

Answer (score 0):

You can use django-crispy-forms https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

in your settings.py

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3' #or bootstrap4
```

With that your template will look like this

```
{% extends 'applicant/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<center>
    <!-- Default unchecked -->
    <form method = "post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
</center>
{% endblock %}
```